# Exponent program using while loop no " ** "

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to use a while loop to get an exponent raised to the nth power. I cant use the ** operator and I tried several different ways but it still wont display the right numbers. Is there anything I can do to fix it?

Implement the same function using a while loop, instead of a for loop.

```
def i_power(base,power):

    count = 0
    while power >= 0:
        count = count + (base * (count + 1))
        print(count)

i_power(3,8)
```

for this problem I am expecting the output to be 6561 but the actual output is a bunch of huge numbers and never ends.

Comment: You don't decrement power hence end up in an infinite loop, Also not sure why yoy are adding to count

Comment: Your loop condition checks the value of `power`, but the loop body doesn't modify `power`, so the condition is always true.

Answer (score 0):

```
def i_power(base,power):

    count = 1
    while power > 0:
        count = count * (base)
        power-=1
        print(count)

i_power(3,8)
```

You are not decrement power variable

Comment: Thank you so much. Its looking more like it should

Comment: Don’t forget to vote the answer, if it helped you